# The named parameter 'textColor' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error when writing for example color or textColor maybe even with more.
I tried:

flutter clean -> everything is now red, even after restarting. I have to use
'flutter pub get' to get it back to normal

restating PC

ctrl + shift + p -> Dart: Restart Analysis Server
Nothing changes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        textColor: Colors.green,
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have no idea what to do and I'm starting to hate this language more and more
Some help would really be appreciated

Comment: `textColor` is not a valid property for [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html).

Comment: ok, i'll look into that.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Answer 1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```